# get values from model to link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

these are the links I have now to filter some campaigns:

```
            <ul>
                <li><%= link_to "Owner", :role_id => "1" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Manager", :role_id => "2" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Agent", :role_id => "3" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Participant", :role_id => "4" %></li>
            </ul>
```

role id's are specified in  campaign_membership.rb

```
ROLE = {'owner' => 1, 'manager' => 2, 'agent' => 3, 'participant' => 4}
```

the way I built links probably are not the right way, they are hardcoded, how can I assign this role_id in another more appropriate way?

something like using

```
CampaignMembership::ROLE::owner
CampaignMembership::ROLE::manager
CampaignMembership::ROLE::agent
CampaignMembership::ROLE::participant
```

inside the link.

Thank you.

details:

2 tables, `users` and `campaigns` are linked by a 3-d one, `campaign_membership`, in campaign membership I have `user_id`, `campaign_id` and `role_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# in your config
ROLE = {'owner' => 1, 'manager' => 2, 'agent' => 3, 'participant' => 4}

# in your view:
<ul>
  <% ROLE.each do |k,id| %>
  <li><%= link_to t("roles."+k), :role_id => id %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

# in your config/locales/en.yml
en:
  roles:
    owner: Owner
    manager: Manager
```

Comment: you are f... awesome :)  give me 3 minutes to accept your answer, I can do it only after 5 minutes